# Converting a List of Strings to a List of custom made objects in Java using Lambda Expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

So I have something like this :

```
List<String> persons = Arrays.asList("Tom","Harry", "Steve");
```

I want to convert it to a `List<Person>` using Lambda Expressions.

Assume Person is the following class :

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() { 
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

I have been trying various things with forEach, map, etc, but not able to get the code to work.

Thanks.

Comment: I have seen that earlier. This isn't a duplicate question. It's a different scenario here as Person is a 3rd party class that can't be changed. So, I would have needed the suggestion of creating the lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add a constructor to your `Person` class that takes a string, you can just use:

```
List<Person> people = persons.stream()
    .map(Person::new)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you don't have a constructor, then you will need a lambda:

```
List<Person> people = persons.stream()
    .map(s -> { Person p = new Person(); p.setName(s); return p; })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Perfect!! This works, thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

First is better you modify you `Person` class, adding another constructor passing the name.

```
public class Person {
    public Person() {}
    public Person(String name) { this.name = name; }
    private String name;
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

After that, just need execute this code:

```java
List<String> persons = Arrays.asList("Tom","Harry", "Steve");
List<Person> result = persons
        .stream()
        .filter(name -> name != null) // logical expression to remove invalid elements of the result collection
        .map(name -> new Person(name))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Actually, I can't change Person. Consider it as something supplied by a 3rd party vendor. But thanks, I will keep this knowledge for some other use case.

Comment: But if you can't modify the `Person` class you have to code a little bit more

Comment: I'm of the opinion that if `null` is provided as a value, it should not be silently removed from the list unless the method caller is expecting that behavior. It would also be inappropriate to put that logic in the stream. The null check should be done by the `Person` class, assuming `null` is an invalid name for a `Person` in the first place.

Comment: @4castle All depends what you want to do, this piece of code is just an example what we can do with streams, it could be any logical expression.